# Cannot save the state of Qt drawing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Maybe it is insufficient knowledge of Qt or of Python, of maybe even both, but I have a problem with Qt5 in Python.

I have a script that draws a line from a point where the mouse pointer is depressed to the point where it is released. That works fine.

Then when I want to draw a second line, I want to keep the first line on the QDialog as well, but because the way paintEvent works that is not possible straight away.

There for I've created a helper class (at first it was in the MyDialog class itself) to store all the points in a list and then use this class to redraw all the lines when paintEvent redraws the QDialog.

However, this is not working because for some reason all the points stored in the helper class get overridden by the last point. So if I draw ten lines, the helper class has 10 times the last (10th) point in its list.

Below you can see the code, can somebody shine a light on this? Thank!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPicture
from demoDrawLine import *

class ContextTest:
    test = []

class MyForm(QDialog):
    picture = []

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drawing = []
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.pos1 = [0,0]
        self.pos2 = [0,0]
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.drawLine(self.pos1[0], self.pos1[1], self.pos2[0], self.pos2[1])
        qp.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.pos1[0], self.pos1[1] = event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.pos2[0], self.pos2[1] = event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()
        ContextTest.test.append((self.pos1, self.pos2))
        self.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here some results I copied from the debugger:

1st line drawn: ContextTest.test : [([150, 335], [452, 618])]
2nd line drawn: ContextTest.test : [([311, 695], [340, 666]), ([311, 695], [340, 666])]
3rd line drawn: ContextTest.test : [([1444, 249], [1043, 712]), ([1444, 249], [1043, 712]), ([1444, 249], [1043, 712])]
etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving the points in test but you are not using it to paint, as you realized paintEvent has no notion of the past so you will have to save those points but better than saving points would be to keep instructions that know how to paint, for example it could add other figures without needing to write a lot of code in it.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Instruction:
    def paint(self, painter):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class LineInstruction(Instruction):
    def __init__(self, line):
        self._line = line
    def paint(self, painter):
        painter.drawLine(self._line)

class ContextTest:
    instructions = []

class MyForm(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drawing = []
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        for instruction in ContextTest.instructions:
            instruction.paint(qp)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.start = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        l = QtCore.QLine(self.start, event.pos())
        instruction = LineInstruction(l)
        ContextTest.instructions.append(instruction)
        self.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```